# Making a list of cards with Base ,derived classes , & multi inherited classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a list of cards for my game and i have A Base class called Card , and childeren class of Card called (MonsterCard, LocationCard , Artifact Card ... etc ) I wanted to seperate all the cards because they would have added on Properties that others wouldn't like MonsterCards , have Health ,Power and The LocationCard wouldn't have that but have something called an E-boost.

i created a new class called CardDataBase that would build the cards however for some reason when i make a list like this:

```
List<Card> cardlist = new list < card> ();

cardlist.Add (new MonsterCard(10 Arguments ));

cardlist.Add (new LocationCard (4 arguments));
```

This is what My Card & MonsterCard classes look like :

```
 public Card() 
    {

    }
    public Card(int Id, string CardName, string Description, Element Element)
    {
        id = Id;
        cardName = CardName;
        description = Description;
        element = Element;
    }
```

, and MonsterCard Class

```
 public MonsterCard() { } 

    public MonsterCard(int Id, string CardName, string Description, Element Element, Role Role, MonsterType MonsterType  ,int Health, int Power, int Speed, int Wisdom, int UltimatePoints, int PotentialShield): base(Id, CardName,Description, Element)
    {
        role = Role;
        monsterType = MonsterType;
        health = Health;
        power = Power;
        speed = Speed;
        wisdom = Wisdom;
        ultimatePoints = UltimatePoints;
        potentialShield = PotentialShield;
    }
```

Furthermore: I also Created a class called Display card that is suppose to display the card onto my unity Card Prefab. Like so:

```
public List<Card> displayCard = new List<Card>();
    public int displayId;

    public int id;
    public string cardName;
    public string description;
    public int health;
    public int power;
    public int speed;
    public int wisdom;
    public int potientialShield;
    public int ultimatePoints;
    public enum Role
    {
        Leader,
        Champion,
        Support,
        Tank,
        Scout,
    }
    public enum MonsterType
    {
        Demon,
        Dragon,
        Fairy,
        Fiend,
        Plant,
        Psychic,
        Pyro,
        Reptile,
        Rock,
        Spellcaster,
        Thunder,
        Warrior,
        Zombie
    }
    public enum Element
    {
        Fire,
        Water,
        Earth,
        Air,
        Light,
        Dark
    }
    public Element element;
    public Role role;
    public MonsterType monsterType;

    public Text nameText;
    public Text descriptionText;
    public Text elementText;
    public Text healthText;
    public Text powerText;
    public Text speedText;
    public Text wisdomText;
    public Text potentialShieldText;
    public Text ultimatePointsText;
    public Text roleText;
    public Text monsterTypeText;

     void Start()
    {
        displayCard[0] = CardDataBase.cardList[displayId];
    }

     void Update() 
    {
        id = displayCard[0].id;
        cardName = displayCard[0].cardName;
        description = displayCard[0].description;
        element = (Element)displayCard[0].element;
        role = (Role)displayCard[0].role;
        monsterType = (MonsterType)displayCard[0].monsterType;
        health = displayCard[0].health;
        power = displayCard[0].power;
        speed = displayCard[0].speed;
        wisdom = displayCard[0].wisdom;
        potientialShield = displayCard[0].potentialShield;
        ultimatePoints = displayCard[0].ultimatePoints;

        nameText.text = " " + cardName;
        descriptionText.text = " " + description;
        elementText.text = " " + element;
        healthText.text = " " + health;
        powerText.text = " " + power;
        speedText.text = " " + speed;
        wisdomText.text = " " + wisdom;
        potentialShieldText.text = " " + potentialShieldText;
        ultimatePointsText.text = " " + ultimatePoints;
        roleText.text = " " + role;
        monsterTypeText.text = " " + monsterType;

}
}
```

but for some reason it says that "Card" Does not contain a definition for element,role ,Monstertype, etc.

The problem here is that since cardList is List it doesnt reconize all the variables / Aurguments that My MonsterCard class holds

I've tried adding the definitions for role, health ...etc on the card class but shouldnt it already be able to use that from the derived classes ... if not what am i suppose to do ?

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear to me. That said, the base class `Card` will never know about the properties/fields in the derived classes. But the derived classes will know about the base properties and fields. Also, when you try to convert I think you need another set of parentheses; so instead of this...`element = (Element)displayCard[0].element;` you would want to do this, `element = ((Element)displayCard[0]).element;`. Notice the additional parentheses that wrap the type conversion, now `.element` should be recognized.

Comment: i edit my post to try to make the question more clear @quaabaam

Answer (score 0):

Like @quaabaam, I'm not quite following, but...

The right way to do what I think you are trying to do is to use *virtual functions* (with the `virtual` and `override`keywords). In your base class you provide virtual methods for your primary methods (say `Display`, `Update` and `Clone`). Then in each subclass you override them in a class-specific way, using class-specific properties and possibly class-specific methods.

Then if you want to update a collection of cards, you loop through the collection, calling `Update` on each card. This will result in each card having its class-specific `Update` method called.

For `Clone`, look at the `IClonable` interface (and wonder why Microsoft didn't come up with `IClonable<T>` in 2005 - its clone method would return a `T` instead of an `object`). I recommend that you create one in your project if you need to duplicate your cards:

```
public interface ICloneable<T> where T class, new() 
{
    public T Clone();
}
```

Then you'd declare your `Card` class to implement `IClonable<Card>`:

```
public class Card : IClonable<Card>
{
    //Implementation 
}
```

A less satisfying (and less elegant) way to do this is to use *pattern matching* `if` or `switch` statements:

```
if (card is MonsterCard mCard) 
{
   mCard.SomethingMonsterSpecific();
}
```